# Use fragments ans swipe views without extend fragmentsActivity

Tags: java, android

my main activity have classic tabs, I want to implement swipable tabs in my main actuvity,
But in every tutorial/guide I've found, each time main activity extends FragmentActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
```

But, I have other things in my activity, so my main activity extends Activity, 
My a question is : how to add all fragments, view pager and other methods, in activity that just extend activity ?

Source http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To host fragments, an activity needs the `FragmentManager` and so needs to extend `FragmentActivity`, the one from the standard library, or the one from the Support library.

There is no other choice.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. So how can I keep all my methods working when I extend activity without extending Activity ?

Comment: `FragmentActivity` extends itself `Activity` of course